# How do I retrieve specific Column Data

Tags: php

I've been messing around with PHP once again. I am trying to retrieve information from a specific Column. So for example I'll do

http://127.0.0.1:8002/api/galaxy/rgalaxy.php?api&Name=Hi

The Column looks like this.

```
    +----------------+-------+
    | Name           | Data  |
    +----------------+-------+
--> | Hi             |  Grab | <--
    | Medium product |  9.99 |
    | Large product  | 15.99 |
    +----------------+-------+
```

And It'll retrieve this info **Grab**
So since I put in Hi As the Parameter, It'll retrieve Grab

I have no idea how to do that. Would anyone mind helping?

Comment: What is your data source?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Data Source? I am using MYSQL if that helps.

Comment: The link you posted doesn't work, of course. There is a reason why `127.0.0.1` is also known as `localhost`, isn't it?

Comment: The link I posted isn't supposed to work. It was an example.

Comment: it will work on your machine not any other place.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your MySQL query will look something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE Name=$_GET['Name']"
```

Then you need to run the above query, and fetch it into a PHP variable and do whatever you want with that. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hmm! Okay, That did something. It shows a blank page here is my full code `<?php
include 'dbstars.php';

  $name = ($_GET['Name']) ; // escape your variable here .

  $output = mysql_query("SELECT Data FROM `Galaxy` WHERE $name") or die(mysql_error()) ;
  echo $output
}
?>
`

Comment: Your column names are 'Name' and 'Data', so obviously 'Testing' as a column name will return Unknown Column name error.

Comment: Okay, so how would I retrieve  `  +----------------+-------+
    | Name           | Data  |
    +----------------+-------+
--> | Hi             |  Grab | <--
    | Medium product |  9.99 |
    | Large product  | 15.99 |
    +----------------+-------+` The arrow highlighted bit? Maybe I'm just understanding it wrong and need to look it again tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, if you have more than the 2 column names you can use * as the returning column list. it will return all columns. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Well thanks! That fixed it. I figured out the issue. Turns out FileZilla wasn't uploading the updated script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE other_column = 'value'";
```

replace "column_name", "table_name", "other_column" and "value" by desired.

To get your 'Name' value from url use `$_GET['Name']`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, open a connection to your database

`$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db_username', 'db_password, 'db_name');`

Then, use this connection to perform your query

**Edit :** to avoid SQL injection

```
<?php
$name = '';

if(isset($_GET['Name'])){

    $name = $_GET['Name'];
}

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ett');

$query = 'SELECT name FROM items WHERE name like ?';

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$names_array = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $names_array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I suppose I'm just going to have to store all of the column's into an array and filter out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this Mysql query if you want only Data  value as Grab

$name=$_GET['Name'];
$sql = "SELECT Data FROM `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` WHERE Name='.$name.'  ";

and if you want to fetch more data like

```
 | Hi             |  Grab | 
| Medium product |  9.99 |
| Large product  | 15.99 |
```

all then you need to add one more column who's value is common to all row and pass those column value to your url .

Comment: Alright! That works. However, how would I echo that? I try to do
`<?php
include 'dbstars.php';
  if(isset($_GET['api'])) {
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT Data FROM Galaxy WHERE Name=`".$_GET['Name']."`");
  while ($output = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo json_encode($output);
 }
}
?>
` And it doesn't show anything